# relation between exponentials in modulus operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am high school student preparing myself to math olympics, I found the following question in my text book written in Hungarian,but I have translated it into English

Assume that we are in group $Z_p^*$ under multiplication operation. Our $p=97$ , It is observed that for any generator $k$ of $p$, $k^{x_1}=2$ and $k^{x_2}=5$ under modulo operation where $x_1$ is always even number and $x_2$ is always odd number.

I want to see the reason behind why $x_1$ is always even number and $x_2$ is always odd number. I know that $5$ is one of the primitve root of $97$, but what is the reason, is it a coincide ?

Can you please explain it, if you give links in your answers, i can learn the new terms and topics. I am smart high school student but if you write your answers detaily, it would be better for me .

Comment: Hint: what is the order of $2\pmod {97}$?  What about $5$?

Comment: @lulu 5 is generator,so its order is $p-1=96$, but it is even integer. question says that $k_2$ is odd

Comment: @lulu am I wrong ?

Comment: $5^{96}\equiv 1$ and $5^{97}\equiv5\bmod 97$; $97$ is odd

Comment: @J.W.Tanner but the other generators are derive from $x_2$ where $x_2$ and $96$ are coprime. I could not understand

Comment: If $5\equiv k^{2n}$ then $5^{48}\equiv \left(k^{2n}\right)^{48}=\left(k^{96}\right)^n\equiv1^n=1\pmod{97}$, contradicting that $5$ is a generator

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k$ is a generator if and only if its multiplicative order modulo $97$ is $96$.

Since $5$ is a primitive root modulo $97$, it has multiplicative order $96$, as does $k$. But the order of $k^a$ is $\frac{96}{\gcd(96,a)}$.
So if $k^{x_2}\equiv 5\pmod{97}$, then $\gcd(96,x_2)=1$, so $x_2$ is odd.

For $2$, note that the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $96$ is $48$. That means that the order of $k^{x_1}$ must satisfy $48=\frac{96}{\gcd(96,x_1)}$, which requires $\gcd(x_1,96)=2$. In particular, $x_1$ must be even.